# Please welcome your newest pro tem moderator

Tags: discussion, moderators

I'm Pops, a Community Manager at Stack Exchange. As some of you may have noticed, one of your moderators recently stepped down for personal reasons. I'm happy to announce that a great new pro tem mod is taking his place:

[image: KevinReidAG6YO]

Any of you with more than a passing familiarity with this site will surely recognize Kevin from his numerous helpful posts on both the main site and on meta. Please join me in welcoming him to the mod team, and in thanking Michael for his service!

Answer (score 3):

Thank you.

I've been doing what I can to make Amateur Radio Stack Exchange be a successful site since it was an Area 51 proposal. As a moderator, I intend to make sure that issues that need attention get it — perhaps by exercising my powers, but also by drawing the community's attention when that is a sufficient solution.

This is my first time being a moderator, and I suspect I may make mistakes — I‘m not used to having, for example, binding close votes, which require a different threshold than my previous role of “enthusiastic participant in the process”. Please feel free to give me feedback — I value second opinions on my judgement.

Comment: Welcome to the team!